# Scroll the entire page with with UITableView that doesn't take up the entire screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview

The only UITableViews I have worked with thus far are sized to fill the entire page.

I'm trying to create a page in my app where I will have an image and a label on the top of the page followed by a UITableView to hold comments below it.

Something like this springs to mind: http://www.inquisitr.com/wp-content/fbb.jpg

My problem is if I add a UITableView below the image and label, when I scroll the tableview then only the UITableView cells scroll. Not the entire page.

How would I go about making the entire page scroll so that the label and image scroll off the page and more table cells appear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image and label in a container `UIView`, and then set that container to the [`tableHeaderView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView) property of your `UITableView`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware there was a tableHeaderView property. This looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `tableHeaderView` property of the `UITableView` to a custom view containing your controls.